# Canvas Get Shape Rotation Value

Tags: html, canvas, rotation, kineticjs

I've searched endlessly for a way to obtain the actual rotation val/deg of a shape on my canvas.

http://www.rfgraham.net/demos/canvas-spinner

As you see here I have a circle with an arrow in the middle. When you click on the canvas, the arrow starts spinning. Click again to stop the arrow and it will output to the console the current rotation value stored for the arrow obj.

I'm not strong at math and I grabbed the animation code from Kineticjs as this is the library i'm using. However the code i've chosen may be the culprit for the rotation value i'm getting back.

My objective is to figure out which of the 4 quarters of the circle the arrow lands on. If i could somehow get the current rotation out of 360 degrees, i could do something like -

```
var rotation = 360 / arrow.rotate.val

if(rotation <= 90) {
     console.log("First quarter")
}
```

All I get however is one full rotation = 6.xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your code does have the answer, attrs.rotation, which shows radians(theta)

```
  console.log(arrowGrp.attrs.rotation)  //shows radian
```

You can simply change this to degree.

```
  console.log(arrowGrp.attrs.rotation * (180/Math.PI) % 360)  //shows degrees
```

FYI, Formulas to convert between radians and degrees are.

```
  degrees = radians * (180/Math.PI)
  radians = degrees * (Math.PI/180)
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are radians, so a half turn, in degrees "180", is 1*pi (3.1415[...]) and a full turn, in degrees "360", is 2*pi (6.28....)

Get the value, let's call it v, and find out how many times Math.PI it is:

```
var v = arrow.rotate.val;
var percent = 2*Math.PI/v;
var degrees = 360 * percent;
```

But the real answer is of course "you don't need it in degrees". Whether the number runs from 0 to 6.28 or from 0 to 360 is irrelevant as long as you know which number a full turn is. In this case, 2*Math.PI, so just work with that =)